# Ways to access a JavaScript Object's Property in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6, ckeditor

I have a JavaScript object with some properties. Lets say:

```
var haystack = {
  foo: {value: "fooooo"},
  bar: {value: "baaaaa"}
};
```

Now, I want to access one of those properties, but I don't know which one. Luckily, this variable does:

```
var needle = "foo";
```

In modern browsers I seem to be able to do the following and it works:

```
haystack[needle].value;  # returns "fooooo"
```

But in IE6 it throws a wobbly, `haystack[...] is null or not an object`.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve in IE6? If so, how so?

---

EDIT - Adding further information in response to the comments below...

---

What I am trying to achieve is actually related to CKEditor. I haven written a plugin image manager that opens in an iframe.

What I then want to achieve is to place the chosen image back in the correct instance of CKEditor (and there can be more than one instance on some pages).

What I have done (and I know this is an ugly hack), when the iframe is opened I have put a hidden field next to it with the name of the instance. So the parent page contains some markup like this:

```
<iframe><!-- Image manager --></iframe>
<input type="hidden" id="ckinstance" value="article_body" />
```

So then, inside the iframe when an image is selected to be inserted I have some JavaScript that looks like this:

```
var CKEDITOR = window.parent.CKEDITOR;
var instance = window.parent.$('#ckinstance').val();
var img = '<img src="/whatevers/been/selected" />';
CKEDITOR.instances[instance].insertHtml(img);
window.parent.$.modal.close();
```

This works fine in FF, Chrome, etc. Just IE6 is complaining with:

```
CKEDITOR.instances[...] is null or not an object.
```

EDIT 2

I've just done some debugging and actually it looks like IE6 is failing on `window.parent.$('#ckinstance').val()` and is returning undefined.

So the original problem that I've described is not the problem at all.

Still need help though :)

Comment: no reason that wont work, it square bracket notation which isnt modern.. could you provide an example?

Comment: Yup, this should work in IE6 as well. Can you show an example?

Comment: An SSCCE for you: http://jsbin.com/uzomo3/.  Works fine in IE6.

Comment: I've elaborated a little and added the "real life" problem above. The problem is obviously not as simple as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite annoying when you spend a couple of hours scratching your head over something, only to realise the solutions is:

```
Tools > Internet Options > Delete Files
```